# Tour module doesn't start

Tags: theming

I am using Drupal 7, along with a Bootstrap 3 (simplecorp) and I am attempting to create a site tour using the [Bootstrap Tour Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_tour), which of course has no documentation beyond the project page.

I successfully installed all of the dependencies for the Bootstrap Tour Module (bootstrap.css, bootstrap.tooltip.js, bootstrap.popover.js) and I am successfully able to manually implement both tooltips and popovers flawlessly. I also host the bootstrap tour library locally, not via cdnjs.

I initialize the tooltips and popovers using the code below (NOTE: the project page for Bootstrap Tour doesn't indicate if the popovers need to be initialized or if the module itself performs that task (I have tested the Bootstrap Tour module with and without my own initialization code.)

```
(function($) {
$(function() {
  $(document).tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' });
  $(document).popover({ selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]' });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Within my stylesheet, I created the following css selectors:

```
a#teststep1 { font-weight:bold;color:red;}
a#teststep2 { font-weight:bold;color:blue;}
a#teststep3 { font-weight:bold;color:green;}
```

Then I configured the Bootstrap Tour Module to create a " Test_Tour " with two steps using a#teststep1 and a#teststep2 as css selectors for each step.... a#teststep3 above is to manually test the operation of my popovers.

As instructed by the project page instructions, I set the tour to automatically run using " ?tour=Test_Tour " at end of my url /path.

I link to myPath/?tour=Test_Tour from my homepage, but when I land on the test page that has page html elements containing the css selector id(s) above, nothing happens, no popovers, no tour starts.

Am I configuring something wrong? Or is there a bug and can someone show me how to manually (programmatically) start the tour?